# T4 data annotation issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to make Data Annotation work with T4 template. 
I Would like to be able to use Display Attribute on entity, [Required], RemoteAttribute etc.

Anybody have an idea ?.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is how to resolve the problem of DataAnnotation with a T4 Generation. 
First of all, let the T4 Generation do his job by  Generating the template.

If you want to add somme DataAnnotation attribute to a variable, you just need to create your own partial class with the same name as the Generated file.

**My Own Partial class on the side**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AuditsMetaData))]
public partial class Audit
{
    public class AuditsMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        public object AuditYear { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you can modify the T4 template.

Comment: Why you cannot create your own partial part?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Because the T4 already generate a partial class. I cannot have multiple same partial class in the same namespace.

Comment: @Pawel yes, I could modify the file generated by the Template generator The problem here is I'm using Database First and I'm at a beginning of the project. I'll probably regenerate the model several time that will result to regenerate the partial class by T4 Template Generator.

Comment: Of course you can have multiple partial classes with the same name in the same namespace - that is a reason for partial keyword existence. At the end all these partial parts forms single class. It is just a helper to divide class code into multiple files.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka you allright, I can create multiple partial class. I Finaly find the way to perform my needs. It's quite simple. I'll update my post to show how with an example. Thanks a lot :)